# why I cannot enable gui for some applications for example gnu octave?

Tags: ssh, snap

I connect remotely with `ssh -XY`. I use xauth to merge the cookies. I can open kate, gedit without any problem. However, I cannot open octave.

The octave is a snap application. But kate is also a snap application though it is classic mode.

The firefox and octave cannot be open and keep complain about the wrong authentication.

```
firefox
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
```

```
octave -f --force-gui
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
octave: unable to open X11 DISPLAY
octave: disabling GUI features
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
GNU Octave, version 7.1.0
Copyright (C) 1993-2022 The Octave Project Developers.
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions.
There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  For details, type 'warranty'.

Octave was configured for "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
```

Answer (score 0):

the snap package looking for .Xauthory at `~/snap/<package>/current/`. I can export a x cookie into that folder or simply `ln -s ~/.Xauthory` in that folder. Then X forwarding works fine.